# How to get the message send from a webhook?

Tags: python, flask, webhooks

I have a woocommerce site set up with a webhook to a python app I have hosted on heroku.

I can't get the message the woocommerce is sending.

The code is here below:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/hook/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hook():
    print(request.get_json())
    return "200 OK"
```

All I need for now is somthing to show up in the heroku log but I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store this message in the database or some other place and then read it and show to the user.

Comment: Yes but isn't that something I need to do to awoide that some messages gets lost due to overload? Woud my code write the message to the log if there is say only one call per hour?

Comment: Actually, this is proper way to do such things. I don't know from where these limitations are coming from, and why you worry about overload. 

Can you access this webhook by yourself and, also, check logs of your WC site?